# Why is the syntax error in the eval() code ignored?

Tags: javascript, browser, theory, interpreter

In function code, when I do this:

```
eval( 'var default = 100;' );
alert( default );
```

the browser's JS engines* will throw a Syntax Error on the *second* statement, as if the first statement executed successfully.

**See here:** http://jsfiddle.net/4FMdy/ (*open the browser's [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525/3382) to view the error log*)

However, when I remove the second statement from the code, so that I only have this:

```
eval( 'var default = 100;' );
```

the browser's JS engines *will* throw a Syntax Error on that statement.

**See here:** http://jsfiddle.net/4FMdy/1/

I don't understand this. If the first statement throws a syntax error (as it should), why does only the second statement throw such an error in my first example above. From what I understand, if a statement throws an error, that necessarily means that all previous statements (of the same call) executed successfully.

Btw, the syntax error is thrown because `default` is a reserved word in JavaScript, so it cannot be used as a variable name.

Also, no "eval is evil" comments please. I'm just trying to understand the behavior of the browser's JS engines.

** I tested in Firefox, and Chrome*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an assumption:

The script-block first will be parsed, but not executed(the eval)

The browser detects only the syntax-error in line#2 and didn't execute complete script-block, so he will not determine the syntax-error in eval()

When you put the 2 lines in 2 different script-element you'll receive both errors:

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/CfRmj/

Comment: Yes, that's it. Now I understand. The stream of tokens first has to be parsed into a *Program*, and only then the resulting program is evaluated. [Info in second paragraph here](http://es5.github.com/#x5.1.4). The tokens `alert`, `(`, `default`, `)`, and `;` are not a valid sequence according to the syntactic grammar. So, the program is not valid, and is therefore **not** evaluated at all. Any syntax error that would appear in the string passed to `eval()` could only be detected once the program is being evaluated, which is *after* it has been parsed according to the syntactic grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Because "default" is Javascript reserved keyword :)

So alert(default) throws "syntax error" if code is checked if is correct, but then the function eval is runned, and process wount get here because of first error.